# jQuery Prepend an Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, prepend

I am trying to add a prepend of an image and then define it's attributes. Little confused as how to do this - currently I have the following but it's not working. The HTML is

```
<div id="testID" class="test1">
        <div id="testID2" class="test2" ></div>
    </div>
```

And the JS is

```
var test123 = somecode{}
jQuery(test123).find('#testID2').prepend('<img />').attr({
   src: 'some src.gif',
   alt: '',
   height: '60'
});
```

I am hoping to achieve

```
<div id="testID" class="test1">
  <div id="testID2" class="test2" >
      <img src='some src.gif' alt='' height='60' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
jQuery("<img/>").prependTo("#testID2").attr({
   src: 'some src.gif',
   alt: '',
   height: '60'
});
```

because from your previous code, you are attaching the attributes to the container and not the img tag

Comment: To debug this kind of thing firebug is really useful as you can see in firebug what is being added where.

Comment: hey thanks alot - just wondering if I have a "find" in there how it works ? i've update the question

Comment: Well, there shouldn't be a need to `find()` for a `#testID2` but the argument to `prependTo()` could easily be `jQuery(test123).find('#testID2')` instead of just `"#testID2"`

Comment: yes, that is correct. But for more complex expressions i suggest you break up the code into multiple lines/expressions.

    var some_img = $("<img/>").attr({...});
    $(test123).find("#testID2").prepend(some_img);

Answer (score 4):

Engwan's answer is a simple way to achieve what you want.  This is just an alternate example where the attributes are set before the `<img>` tag is inserting into the DOM:

```
jQuery(test123).find('#testID2').prepend(
  $('<img />').attr({
   'src': 'some src.gif',
   'alt': '', 
   'height': '60'
  })
);
```